# Click event of notifcation and resume the fragment without changing it UI

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-notifications

```
    I developed a MediaPlayer with background service to handle playing of audio. When song is playing it shows notification of current song and also displaying on lock screen. Now my problem is that when I'm going to click on notification, the fragment, which contains the list of songs, is refreshing. I don't want to refresh the list. I just want to open the specific fragment in its original UI without changing its UI. Following is my code snippet which i use to call Fragment containing Activity.


=============================



Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
             TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
             stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);

    //       Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
             stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
             PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,
             PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext()).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent).setContentTitle(PlayerConstants.SONG_NAME).build();
```

===================

In MainActivity.java following code snippet open the fragment.

=====================

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.details, mFragment, Tag).setTransition(transition).commit();
```

Comment: You need to post the relevant bits of code

Comment: I assume that this refreshing of the list happens when the fragment (and activity) is recreated, right ? And this is done as part of the standard activity and fragment lifecycle

Comment: Thanks helleye. But how can i avoid the fragment being recreated?